# opentk not setting color of triangle correct

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm using opentk using c# and i want set color to my object using uniform but the tiangle color is always black

```
using System;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Common;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
namespace open
{
    class Game : GameWindow
    {

        int VBO, VAO;
        int ShaderProgram;

        public Color4 TriColor { get; set; }

        public void tricolor(Color4 val)
        {
            int loc = GL.GetUniformLocation(VBO, "input_color");
            if (loc == -1)
                throw new Exception("cannot find location of uniform");
            GL.Uniform4(loc, val.R, val.G, val.B, val.A);
            Console.WriteLine("edit color");
            //GL.GetUniform()
        }

        float[] positions = new float[]
        {
              0.0f,  0.5f, 0f,
              0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
             -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f
        };

        public Game() : base(GameWindowSettings.Default, NativeWindowSettings.Default)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("program trying to start");
        }

        protected override void OnResize(ResizeEventArgs e)
        {
            GL.Viewport(0, 0, e.Width, e.Height);
            base.OnResize(e);
        }

        protected override void OnLoad()
        {
            VBO = GL.GenBuffer();
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBO);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, sizeof(float) * positions.Length, positions, BufferUsageHint.DynamicDraw);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);

            VAO = GL.GenVertexArray();
            GL.BindVertexArray(VAO);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBO);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 3 * sizeof(float), 0);
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);

            GL.BindVertexArray(0);


            string vertixShaderCode =
            load_shaders.loadShaderFile(@"C:\Users\Ahmed\source\repos\open\open\vertex shader.shader");


            string FragmentShaderCode = 
                load_shaders.loadShaderFile(@"C:\Users\Ahmed\source\repos\open\open\fragment shader.shader");

            int VertexShaderHandel = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
            GL.ShaderSource(VertexShaderHandel, vertixShaderCode);
            GL.CompileShader(VertexShaderHandel);

            string Vshaderinfo = GL.GetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderHandel);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(Vshaderinfo);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

            int FragmentShaderHandel = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
            GL.ShaderSource(FragmentShaderHandel, FragmentShaderCode);
            GL.CompileShader(FragmentShaderHandel);

            string Fshaderinfo = GL.GetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderHandel);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(Fshaderinfo);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

            ShaderProgram = GL.CreateProgram();
            GL.AttachShader(ShaderProgram, VertexShaderHandel);
            GL.AttachShader(ShaderProgram, FragmentShaderHandel);

            GL.LinkProgram(ShaderProgram);

            GL.DetachShader(ShaderProgram, VertexShaderHandel);
            GL.DetachShader(ShaderProgram, FragmentShaderHandel);

            GL.DeleteShader(VertexShaderHandel);
            GL.DeleteShader(FragmentShaderHandel);

            tricolor(new Color4(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f));

            base.OnLoad();
        }

        protected override void OnUnload()
        {
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
            GL.DeleteBuffer(VBO);


            GL.UseProgram(0);

            GL.DeleteProgram(ShaderProgram); ;

            base.OnUnload();
        }

        protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs args)
        {
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
            GL.ClearColor(new Color4(0.2f,0.5f,0.7f,1f));

            GL.UseProgram(ShaderProgram);
            GL.BindVertexArray(VAO);
            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 3);

            Context.SwapBuffers();
            base.OnRenderFrame(args);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's vertex shader source code

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 VPos;

uniform vec4 input_color;

out vec4 a_color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(VPos, 1.0);
    a_color = input_color;
}
```

and here's fragment shader source code

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 final_color;

in vec4 a_color;

void main() {
    final_color = a_color;
}
```

i tried to change the uniform by using GL.Uniform4(loc, val.R, val.G, val.B, val.A); instead of GL.Uniform4(loc, val); but the same result appear

Answer (score 0):

`GL.Uniform*` sets the value of a variable in the default uniform block of the currently installed program. Therefore, you need to install the program with `GL.UseProgram` before you can set the uinform:

```cs
GL.UseProgram(ShaderProgram); 
tricolor(new Color4(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f));
```

Alternatively, you can use the direct state access version of [`glUniform*`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) which is [`glProgramUniform*`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glProgramUniform.xhtml):

```
GL.ProgramUniform4(ShaderProgram, loc, val.R, val.G, val.B, val.A);
```